# Composing Selectors inside "Extra Selectors" throws: Cannot access 'selectFirstFilteredBook' before initialization

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

Using a selector inside it sibling throws an error `Cannot access 'selectFirstFilteredBook' before initialization`. Is it intended behavior and I am missing something or is it a limitation of `extraSelectors`?

Here is an example:

```
export const booksFeature = createFeature({
name: 'books',
reducer: createReducer(
initialState,
on(BookListPageActions.search, (state, action) => ({
       ...state,
       query: action.query,
    })),
   ),

extraSelectors: ({ selectQuery, selectBooks }) => ({

selectFilteredBooks: createSelector(
  selectQuery,
  selectBooks,
       (query, books) => books.filter(book => book.title.includes(query)),
     ),

selectFirstFilteredBook: createSelector( //<<<--- Selector that throws error
  selectFilteredBooks,
       (filteredBooks) => filteredBooks[0],
     ),
   }),
});`
```

If its a not supported behavior, the only solution I see would be to duplicate `selectFilteredBooks` logic inside `selectFirstFilteredBook` and that´s just ugly.

Moreover, if described behaviour is not possible it makes impossible creating a decent View Model selector which is a deal breaker.

Does anyone have a solution/workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I can help you. Instead of returning the object with all selectors you can save the selectors in some variables and return the object afterwards.
In your example:

```js
extraSelectors: ({ selectQuery, selectBooks }) => {
  const selectFilteredBooks = createSelector(
    selectQuery,
    selectBooks,
    (query, books) => books.filter(book => book.title.includes(query))
  );
  const selectFirstFilteredBook = createSelector(
    selectFilteredBooks,
    (filteredBooks) => filteredBooks[0],
  );
  return {
    selectFilteredBooks,
    selectFirstFilteredBook
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it answers your question!

Comment: Sorry for delay. Just tested it. Great solution! Thank you